# ant design customize theme vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

i got my vue3 application setup so far with tailwind, and ant design but can't customize ant design theme
i am following this [guide](https://antdv.com/docs/vue/customize-theme/)

i got this error

```
 error  in ./node_modules/ant-design-vue/es/button/style/index.less

Syntax Error: TypeError: this.getOptions is not a function


 @ ./node_modules/ant-design-vue/es/button/style/index.less 4:14-207 15:3-20:5 16:22-215
 @ ./node_modules/ant-design-vue/es/button/style/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--13-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--1-0!./node_modules/vue-loader-v16/dist??ref--1-1!./src/views/About.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js
 @ ./src/views/About.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js
 @ ./src/views/About.vue
 @ ./src/router/index.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.8.57:8080&sockPath=/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js
```

i have this in `vue.config.js`

```js
css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      less: {
        lessOptions: {
          modifyVars: {
            'primary-color': '#1DA57A',
            'link-color': '#1DA57A',
            'border-radius-base': '2px',
          },
          javascriptEnabled: true,
        },
      },
    },
  },
```

i've also installed less and less loader.

```
"less": "^4.1.2",
"less-loader": "^10.2.0",
```

and here is my `babel.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset'],
  plugins: [['import', { libraryName: 'ant-design-vue', libraryDirectory: 'es', style: true }]],
};
```

am i doing anything wrong here

Answer (score 0):

You have to import the file `antd.less` as follows in `main.js`:

```
import * as Vue from 'vue'
import axios from 'axios'
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'
import App from './App.vue'
import Antd from 'ant-design-vue';
import 'ant-design-vue/dist/antd.css';
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import 'ant-design-vue/dist/antd.less'

const app = Vue.createApp(App)
.use(store)
.use(router)
.use(Antd)
.use(VueAxios, axios)
app.mount('#app')
```

And your `vue.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      less: {
        lessOptions: {
          modifyVars: {
            'primary-color': '#f6b26b',
            'link-color': '#f6b26b',
            'border-radius-base': '10px',
          },
          javascriptEnabled: true,
        },
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: Please don't post images of text, post the text itself